# Phoenix Js and Audio files adding

Tags: javascript, audio, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am new in elixir development. I have couple sounds and js files which I add to my assets folder. When I am trying to access them I got an error

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:4000/js/calls.js 404 (Not Found)
call:1 GET http://127.0.0.1:4000/sounds/ringtone.wav 
call:1 GET http://127.0.0.1:4000/sounds/ringbacktone.wav 404 (Not Found)
call:1 GET http://127.0.0.1:4000/assets/sounds/dtmf.wav 404 (Not Found)
call:1 GET http://127.0.0.1:4000/assets/sounds/ringtone.wav 404 (Not Found)
call:1 GET http://127.0.0.1:4000/assets/sounds/ringbacktone.wav 404 (Not Found)
call:1 GET http://127.0.0.1:4000/sounds/dtmf.wav 404 (Not Found)
```

But the sound files already in assets folder and conn.js also in js folder. This is sample code how can I connected  call.js to html

```
 <script src="<%= static_path(@conn, "/js/call.js") %>"></script>
```

From the book which I read I understood that if I want to make task management in phoenix for creating `app.js` I should need to use brunch. But in my situation I want to use javascript  and sound files as seperate without task manager. My first question how can I access to  javascript and sound files in phoenix? My second question as you can from the error list above it tryed to access to twice `dtmf.wav` file and other files. But inside of the html code I wrote this in one place why it tried to check this in two folders?

```
call:1 GET http://127.0.0.1:4000/assets/sounds/dtmf.wav 404 (Not Found)
call:1 GET http://127.0.0.1:4000/sounds/dtmf.wav 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your endpoint.ex file, i believe you need to add the folder of your sounds.

lib -> AppName -> endpoint.ex

```
  plug Plug.Static,
    at: "/", from: :heaped, gzip: false,
    only: ~w(css fonts images sounds js favicon.ico robots.txt)
```

If sounds is the name of the folder. :-)

Comment: Thanks for response I already add that. The problem is it again show error for custom js files.